# Why is $C_{V}$ allowed in this equation $\Delta E_{int} = nC_{V}\Delta T$ for an adiabatic process?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, adiabatic

Since in an adiabatic process volume and pressure are changing I don't get how it's valid to use $C_{V}$ since that's the molar specific heat at **constant volume**. I must be missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal energy of an ideal gas is a function only of temperature.  So, for an ideal gas, it doesn't matter whether the volume is constant or not.  The subscript v refers to how $C_v$ of a gas can be **measured** experimentally, not how it is applied in practice.  $C_v$ can be **measured** experimentally by directly determining the amount of heat transferred Q to bring about a temperature change $\Delta T$ in a test at constant volume.  In such a test, no work is done, so $\Delta E=Q$.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the constant pressure equation $Q=nC_{p}\Delta T$ then? That equation is given as well but the constants will be different meaning the heat will be different, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason.  $C_p$ relates to the effect of temperature on enthalpy H.  The enthalpy of a ideal gas is a function only of temperature.  So, for an ideal gas, it doesn't matter whether the pressure is constant or not.  The subscript p refers to how $C_p$ of a gas can be measured experimentally, not how it is applied in practice.  $C_p$ can be measured experimentally by directly determining the amount of heat transferred Q to bring about a temperature change $\Delta T$ in a test carried out at constant pressure.  In such a case, $\Delta H=Q$

Comment: Ok, I'll have to ask my professor about that. I've never seen enthalpy before and it's not even listed in the index of our textbook (it's Physics 1, though).

Comment: Then how did you hear about $C_p$?  $C_p$ is **defined** as the derivative of the enthalpy per unit mass (or per mole) with respect to temperature at constant pressure.

Comment: They define it as heat required to raise 1 mol of gas by 1 degree Celsius at either constant volume or constant pressure, and then they plug it into $Q=mc\Delta T$ (not directly obviously, but with some manipulation). Enthalpy is never mentioned anywhere, which I guess is odd. What was bothering me was on our equation sheet we're given $ Q=n C_{v}\Delta T$ and also $Q=n C_{p}\Delta T$, but if you set those equal to each other you get two different constants equal to each other, so I figured they could only be used if it was either at constant volume or constant pressure.

Comment: When we studied freshman physics, we used these (simplistic) definitions.  However, when we got to thermodynamics, we realized that more general definitions were necessary to cover cases in which an arbitrary amount of work was being done.  We recognized that Cv and Cp should be physical properties of the material, and not the path of the process.  In order for that to happen, we sought definitions that preserve the previous relationships that applied when the pressure or volume were constant, while, at the same time representing physical properties of the material for more general cases.

Answer (score 0):

the first law states $$\triangle Q= \triangle I + P \triangle V$$

And for constant V, $\triangle V=0$, therefore we have $$\triangle Q= \triangle I$$

We also know that for constant volume, $$\triangle Q=n C_v \triangle T$$

So we get,
$$\triangle I =  n C_v \triangle T$$